# Background-image in div will not show with position absolute

Tags: html, position, background-image, css

I have to put a background image in a div, if i put only image, it will not show. if i put only height it will be shown.
so in this way it will be shown:

```
<div id="big" style="background-image:url('base1.png');height:200px;"></div>
```

if i want to position div and resize image in this way

```
<div id="big" style="background-image:url('base1.png'); left:519px; top:423px; width:474px; height:205px; z-index:4"></div>
```

it will be not shown. what can i do? can you help me?

Comment: ok, so if i resize manually image, then in which way can i show it?

Comment: If your div has no content, then its height is zero. You need to either place content in it, or set its height, in order for the div to show.

Comment: if i don't use height it will be not shown!

Answer (score 0):

use css

```
<div id="big"></div>

#big {
display:block;
width:300px;
min-height:300px;
background : url('img/image.jpg') no-repeat 50px 50px;
}
```